I want to create an audio waveform view and I want to synchronize it with the audio playback position so I am trying to create an audio editor


fun generateWaveformBitmap(pcmFile: File, width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
    val pcmData = pcmFile.readBytes()
    val bytesPerSample = 2 // 16-bit PCM data
    val samples = pcmData.size / bytesPerSample
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = android.graphics.Canvas(bitmap)
    val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = android.graphics.Color.BLACK
        strokeWidth = 2f
    }


    val maxAmplitude = 32768 // max value for 16-bit PCM data
    val centerY = height / 2

    Log.d("Waveform", "pcmData size: ${pcmData.size}, samples: $samples, width: $width")

    for (i in 0 until width) {
        val sampleIndex = (i * samples) / width

        // Check if sampleIndex is within bounds
        if (sampleIndex in 0 until samples) {
            val startIndex = sampleIndex * bytesPerSample

            // Check if startIndex + bytesPerSample is within pcmData size
            if (startIndex + bytesPerSample <= pcmData.size) {
                val sampleValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(pcmData, startIndex, bytesPerSample).short.toInt()
                val amplitude = (sampleValue.toFloat() / maxAmplitude * centerY).toInt()
                canvas.drawLine(i.toFloat(), (centerY - amplitude).toFloat(), i.toFloat(), (centerY + amplitude).toFloat(), paint)
            } else {
                Log.d("Waveform", "Out of bounds: startIndex + bytesPerSample > pcmData.size, startIndex: $startIndex, bytesPerSample: $bytesPerSample, pcmData size: ${pcmData.size}")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Waveform", "sampleIndex out of bounds: $sampleIndex, samples: $samples")
        }
    }

    return bitmap
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AudioEdit(
    context: Context,
    audioToEdit: File,
   ) {




    val waveformBitmapList = remember { mutableListOf<Bitmap>() }

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val density = LocalDensity.current





    val player = remember { MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.fromFile(audioToEdit))}





    var isPlaying by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
    val isPlaying22 by remember{ derivedStateOf {  isPlaying} }


    val folderName = ObjectFolderPath.MY_APP_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SAVE_FOLDER_NAME
    val appStorageFile = File(context.filesDir, folderName)

    val pcmFilePath = File(appStorageFile, "output.pcm")







    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()

    ) {

        val constraintsBox = constraints

        val halfLayoutWidthInDp by remember {
            mutableStateOf(with(density) { constraintsBox.maxWidth.toDp() } / 2)
        }




        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

            scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                if (pcmFilePath.exists()) {
                    pcmFilePath.delete()
                }

                // Extract PCM data using FFmpeg
                FFmpegKit.execute("-i ${audioToEdit.absolutePath} -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -vn -ac 1 -ar 44100 -y ${pcmFilePath.path}")



                    // Generate waveform bitmap
                    val audioDirectionPerSec = with(density){ player.duration.toDp().toPx()} / 40
                    val audioDirectionPerSecAsDp = audioDirectionPerSec.dp
                    val bitmapWidth = with(density) { audioDirectionPerSecAsDp.roundToPx() }

                    val bitmapHeight: Int = with(density) { (25.dp).roundToPx() }
                    val waveformBitmap =
                        generateWaveformBitmap(pcmFilePath, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight)
                    waveformBitmapList.add(waveformBitmap)



            }

        }





       LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {


               while (true) {



                   if (isPlaying22) {


                       println("Duration${player.duration}")
                       println("currentPosition${player.currentPosition}")

                       val playerDuration = with(density){ (player.duration).toDp().toPx()}

                       val playerCurrentPosition = with(density){player.currentPosition.toDp().toPx()}.coerceAtMost(playerDuration)

                       // this will be used as the percentage value
                       val percentageOfAudioPlayed = (playerCurrentPosition / playerDuration) * 100


                       // this is the width of the first item in the Lazy list  which
                       // is the total constraint width divided by 2 which will be the half of the width
                       val transparentLayoutWidth =  (with(density){constraintsBox.maxWidth.toDp().roundToPx()} ) / 2

                       // this will loop through all the item in the (waveformBitmapList) and get
                       // the  width of each item and add them together which will be the total width
                       val totalWidthOfBitmapInTheList =  with(density){waveformBitmapList[0].width.toDp().toPx()}


                       // this will synchronize the audio play back with the list scrolling
                       val result = if (lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0) {

                           //e.g (25 * 10%) / 100
                           //if the lazyListState is on position 0
                           //but the (waveformBitmapList) is in  itemIndex 1 of the Lazy list

                           (totalWidthOfBitmapInTheList * percentageOfAudioPlayed) / 100
                       } else {


                           // this will get the player position if the Lazy list has reached the end of the transparentLayoutWidth
                           val per =
                               (transparentLayoutWidth / totalWidthOfBitmapInTheList) * 100
                           val pros1 = (per / 100)
                           val pros2 = playerDuration * pros1
                           val pro3 = playerDuration - pros2
                           val playerPreviousPosition = playerDuration - pro3


                           val remainingPosition = playerCurrentPosition - playerPreviousPosition

                           val newPercentage = (remainingPosition / playerDuration) * 100
                           (totalWidthOfBitmapInTheList * newPercentage) / 100


                       }



                       lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(
                           index = lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex,
                           scrollOffset = result.roundToInt()
                       )



                       if (playerCurrentPosition == playerDuration) {
                           player.pause()
                           isPlaying = false

                       }


                   }

                   delay(16)//This should give the UI thread enough time to process other events and remain responsive
               }



       }




        // Synchronize  LazyRow scroll position with  the audio playback position
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = lazyListState) {


            snapshotFlow {

                lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset

            }
                . distinctUntilChanged()


                .collectLatest { _ ->


                    if (waveformBitmapList.isNotEmpty()) {


                        if (!isPlaying) {

                            val firstVisibleItemScrollOffset =
                                lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset


                            val transparentLayoutWidth =
                                (with(density) { constraintsBox.maxWidth.toDp().toPx() }) / 2


                            val percentageScrolled =
                                (with(density) {
                                    firstVisibleItemScrollOffset.toDp().toPx()
                                } / with(density) {
                                    waveformBitmapList[0].width.toDp().toPx()
                                }) * 100


                            val result = if (lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0) {

                                if (!lazyListState.canScrollBackward) {
                                    return@collectLatest
                                }

                                (with(density) {
                                    player.duration.toDp().toPx()
                                } * percentageScrolled) / 100

                            } else {

                                if (!lazyListState.canScrollForward) {
                                    return@collectLatest
                                }

                                val percentageScrolled2 =
                                    ((transparentLayoutWidth + with(density) {
                                        firstVisibleItemScrollOffset.toDp().toPx()
                                    }) / with(density) {
                                        waveformBitmapList[0].width.toDp().toPx()
                                    }) * 100

                                (with(density) {
                                    player.duration.toDp().toPx()
                                } * (percentageScrolled2)) / 100

                            }



                            println("first${lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset}")
                            println("result${result.roundToInt()}")
                            player.seekTo(result.roundToInt())


                        }

                    }


                }

        }





        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.DarkGray)
        ) {


            Button(
                onClick = {

                    if (player.currentPosition < player.duration) {


                        if (!isPlaying) {



                            isPlaying = true


                            player.start()




                        } else {

                            scope.launch {


                                player.pause()

                                isPlaying = false


                            }




                        }
                    }


                }
            ) {
                Text(text = if (isPlaying) "Pause" else "Play")

            }




            val  isItemSelected by remember {
                mutableStateOf(true)
            }

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight()
            ) {

                LazyRow(

                    // flingBehavior = fli,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight(),
                    state = lazyListState,


                    ) {



                    item {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(halfLayoutWidthInDp)
                                .background(Color.Transparent)
                                .height(10.dp)
                        )

                    }




                    if (waveformBitmapList.isNotEmpty()) {

                        itemsIndexed(items = waveformBitmapList, key = { index,bitmapItem -> index }) { index, bitmapItem ->

                            Image(
                                bitmap = bitmapItem.asImageBitmap(),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .background(Color.White)
                                    .animateItemPlacement(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000))

                            )


                        }


                        item {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .width(halfLayoutWidthInDp)
                                    .background(Color.Transparent)
                                    .height(10.dp)
                            )

                        }


                    }


                }





                Canvas( modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight(),
                    contentDescription = "indicator line"
                ) {


                    val segmentHeight = size.height / 17

                    for (i in 0 until 17) {
                        val startY = i * segmentHeight
                        val endY = startY + segmentHeight
                        val color = when {
                            isItemSelected -> if (i % 2 == 0) Color.Red else Color.Yellow
                            else -> if (i % 2 == 0) Color.Red else Color.Transparent
                        }
                        drawLine(
                            color = color,
                            start = Offset(size.width / 2, startY),
                            end = Offset(size.width / 2, endY),
                            strokeWidth = 4f
                        )
                    }


                }






                // this layout will be visible when the audio is playing so that if the audio is playing
                //and you try to scroll the audio will pause and isPlaying will set to false than you can scroll
                if (isPlaying) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectTapGestures {
                                if (isPlaying) {
                                    isPlaying = false
                                    player.pause()
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    )
                }

            }


        }


    }


}


interface AudioRecoder{
fun start(outputFile: File)
fun pause()
fun resume()
fun stopAndSave()


}


I  Extract PCM data using FFmpeg then Generate waveform and saved it in a bitmapImage
i created a LazyRow so that i can scroll through the image and when i am scrolling the audio playback will also changed it position
I also have a fixed indicator line at the center of the screen the indicate the audio position
i want to creat an audio editor
My promble is that my audio play back is not synchronizing with the LazyRow with my audio playback
so that when i scroll audio playback will get it position same as playing the audioaudio loaded and audio playing
